# How can comunicate between component "inside" router-outlet and its siblings in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

This is my main component template:

```
template    : `
                <header></header>
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                <footer></footer>
                <overlayer *ngIf="showPopup"></overlayer>
               `,
directives : [ROUTER_DIRECTIVE, Header, Footer, Popup]
```

Popup is a component/directive that is going to be into "overlayer", but I'd like to display it updating "showPopup" variable from a child component ("inside" router-outlet component)

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: I was looking at that, bit I didn't get if I can user @Input directive on <router-outlet> to comunicate something to a child of a "routed component"

Comment: There is no binding at all with components added by the router and the parent or sibling component. You can use a shared service though.

Comment: The question is unclear